# YM3012 Analog Ground

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, ground, grounding, sound

I am trying to build a circuit using Yamaha Sound chip YM2151 with Yamaha DAC YM3012. This is my first attempt in doing anything with analog signals, so there is much to learn!

While reading a datasheet, I stumbled across the below schematic which shows `Analog Ground`.

Can someone please explain how it works? Why is there 10/15 V if my circuit required 5 V? How do I build this part of the circuit?

[image: example schematic diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only found the 1992 data sheet so maybe yours is later but it did contain a schematic that helps.

I've superimposed your circuit (lower down) with an extract from the data sheet (higher up) and, on your circuit, I've corrected what appears to be a mistake (shown by the red dot): -

[image]

> *Why there is 10/15V if my circuit required 5V?*

It's actually +/- 12 volts to put a number on it. You need to use an external dual supply for the op-amp circuits.

> *How do I build this part of the circuit?*

Get hold of a DC-to-DC converter from the likes of TRACO (for instance) - they produce dual output types and 12 volts (as well as 10 volts and 15 volts) are standard parts. The input supply for the TRACO would nominally be 5 volts and attached to your 5 volt and digital ground.

> *While reading a datasheet I stumbled across below schematic which
>   shows Analog Ground. Can someone please explain how it works?*

Analogue ground is connected to digital ground at just one point (the red circled point that seems to be omitted in your diagram). Any digital circuits in excess of the Yamaha chip will tee-off from that point - this prevents noisy digital currents influencing nice clean analogue currents on the analogue ground.

Comment: Thanks for that. It certainly cleared the mud a bit...
As I understand and read it well I need 4 op-amps on the outputs on pins 9,10,12,15?

Comment: Yes, go with an opamp with gain bandwidth product of greater than  1 MHz.

Comment: I am still new to this... Any chance you can share schematic of how to make the connection to achieve bandwidth of 1MHz?

Comment: It won't have a signal bandwidth of 1 MHz; I said choose an op-amp with a gain-bandwidth-product of greater than 1 MHz (sometimes called unity-gain bandwidth). If you look at an op-amp data sheet (such as TL072) it has a UGB (or GBP) of 3 MHz. That would be a reasonable choice.

Comment: I have LM358 Dual OpAmp. Datasheet says: `Wide Bandwidth (Unity Gain): 1 MHz` but I guess I need something larger so I will look online. Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably be fine with those - maybe fit them on sockets if DIP type and replace later if needed.

Comment: Good Idea! thanks again! This project will be fun if I get to how to program the chip :)

Comment: Good luck with this venture.

Comment: The DAC update rate is about 100 kHz, and it is demultiplexed with two sample and hold channels into two roughly 50 kHz outputs. That's why the datasheet suggests an op-amp with a slew rate of 4V per microsecond. Such op-amps generally have 3-10 MHz GBWP. The chip programming is not that hard.

Answer (score 2):

The insides of the chip has many subcircuits, digital and analog, that may or may not have their grounds internally connected inside the chip. It is therefore the job of the chip user to connect all ground pins externally together to a common ground as shown in the diagram.

This is to have completely separate digital 5V supply for logic chips and analog +/- 12V supply for audio op-amps, so that digital return currents don't flow in the analog section ( or other way around). The digital 0V and analog 0V are only connected together at the YM3012 DAC.

That is just an example, you don't have to do it like that if you don't want to. You can just use single 5V supply and use opamps that work with single 5V supply.

Comment: How do I create analog ground with op-amps? I happen to have some op-amp chips I could use for this I guess?

Comment: You don't create analog ground with op-amps. Either you have one already from your analog supply, or you don't and then you use the digital ground. Anyway, analog and digital ground must be connected preferably at the DAC.

Comment: so if I don't have analog ground I can simply use digital? what is the downside of such connection? Noise?

Comment: I already verified you can just use one single ground. I don't see much downsides, but it might have more noise. It all depends on how you engineer your ground connections and how do return current paths flow in the system. So it depends also on what other stuff the chips are connected and how. Please note that the datasheet example resembles the state of art when it was done - about 40 years ago.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and if I get too much noise I'll get DC-DC converted. One last question... Pins `10` and `9` provide `R/L` output basically to speakers. If I connect them to speakers that already have amplifier, such as standard PC speakers do I need OpAmp there?

Comment: Yes, you most definitely need the op-amp. The outputs from the chip are not "basically" outputs that can be sent to line in directly. And you might want to know that the output diagram does not show a DAC reconstruction filter either, which you most likely want to implement. The datasheet shows only the bare minimum that is required to get two analog outputs with stair-step zero-order-hold analog outputs.